# read a specific string from a file in python?

Tags: python, regex, file, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to read the above file foo.txt and read only UDE from the first line and store it in a variable then Unspecified from the second line and store it in a variable and so on.
should I use read or readlines ? should I use regex for this ?? 
My below program is reading the entire line. how to read the specific word in the line ?

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r+")
line = fo.readline()
left, right = line.split(':')
result = right.strip()
File_Info_Domain = result
print File_Info_Domain
line = fo.readline()
left, right = line.split(':')
result = right.strip()
File_Info_Intention = result
print File_Info_Intention
line = fo.readline()
left, right = line.split(':')
result = right.strip()
File_Info_NLU_Result = result
print File_Info_NLU_Result
fo.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readline()` (without `s` in name) to read line on-by-one, and then you can use `split(':')` to get value from line.

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r+")

# read first line
line = fo.readline()

# split line only on first ':'
elements = line.split(':', 1) 

if len(elements) < 2:
    print("there is no ':' or there is no value after ':' ")
else:
    # remove spaces and "\n"
    result = elements[1].strip()
    print(result)

#
# time for second line
#

# read second line
line = fo.readline()

# split line only on first ':'
elements = line.split(':', 1)

if len(elements) < 2:
    print("there is no ':' or there is no value after ':' ")
else:
    # remove spaces and "\n"
    result = elements[1].strip()
    print(result)

# close
fo.close()
```

Comment: I updated my code but I am getting the error as : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\file.py", line 46, in <module>
    left, right = line.split(':')
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: That's because you have too many values in the third line, it's being splitted at each `:`

Comment: because you have more then one `:` in line and split create more then two elements -  use `elements = line.split(':')` and then `elements[1]` to get element.

Comment: can you update that in the code. it is confusing. Is it correct - # read third line
line = fo.readline()
elements = line.split(':')
elements[1] = elements
result3 = right.strip()
File_Info_NLU_Result = result3
print File_Info_NLU_Result

Comment: btw: you asked for first and second line - third needs modification - split need another argument to slip only on first ':'.

Comment: thanks. but it is just printing {"Location" from the third line. can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: as I said - you asked for first and second line - and you got solution for first and second line :).  `split(':')` splits on every `':'` so in third line you get `elements[2]` and `elements[3]`. Use `split(':', 1)` to split only on first `':'`. See new code.

Comment: I saw that. But how to print the third line completely as -  {"Location": {"literal": "18 Slash 6/2015"}, "Search-phrase": {"literal": "18 slash 6/2015"}}. It is printing UDE and unspecified but not the third line

Comment: Now you have `split(':', 1)` in example. It gives you full line.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use @furas response or regex, I would recommend you to use a config file to do this, instead of a plain txt. So your config file would look like:

```
[settings]
Domain=UDE
Intention=Unspecified
nlu_slot_details={"Location": {"literal": "18 Slash 6/2015"}, "Search-phrase": {"literal": "18 slash 6/2015"}
```

And in your python code:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read("foo.cfg")

domain = config.get('settings', 'Domain')
intention = config.get('settings', 'Intention')
nlu_slot_details = config.get('settings', 'nlu_slot_details')
```

Comment: I agree with you :)  I was going to suggest `json` or `yaml`.

Comment: i am getting an error as : ImportError: No module named configparser

Comment: @akshay if you use Python 2.7 try `ConfigParser`

Comment: You need to install the package. You can do it with pip